# Same Subview for Multi button,Multi View

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

In my application ,i having 4 UIbuttons .On click each button showing subview view contains learn and play option.While clicking , want to show the different view depends on the uibutton selection.Here my code  . please help me to perform diffrent view on click option.

```
-(IBAction)animals
{
  //UIAlertView *alert4=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"LEARN",@"PLAY",@"CANCEL",nil];
//alert4.tag = 4;  
//[alert4 show];///when it was in uialert view

CGPoint point = [tap locationInView:self.birdsbut];
pv = [PopoverView showPopoverAtPoint:point inView:movingview withContentView:alertvu delegate:self];
}
-(IBAction)birds
{

CGPoint point = [tap locationInView:self.birdsbut];
pv = [PopoverView showPopoverAtPoint:point inView:movingview withContentView:alertvu delegate:self];
}
-(IBAction)direct
{ 
 CGPoint point = [tap locationInView:self.birdsbut];
pv = [PopoverView showPopoverAtPoint:point inView:movingview withContentView:alertvu delegate:self];
}
-(IBAction)fruit
{
 CGPoint point = [tap locationInView:self.birdsbut];
pv = [PopoverView showPopoverAtPoint:point inView:movingview withContentView:alertvu delegate:self];
}
```

What  should i add ,to perform multi view option in same click?

Comment: what is the relation with button and UIAlertView ? And what you want now ?

Comment: @MidhunMP before i used uialertview, now i change that into a popover view.So what change should i do for each click in that pop over button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the tag(unique) for all the buttons and then bind them to a same event(IBAction) in touchUpInside.
In the below case bind all of them to the event animals:

```
 -(IBAction) animals: (id) sender;

    ===================================

    -(IBAction) animals: (id) sender {
      NSLog(@"User clicked %@", sender);
      // Do something here with the variable 'sender'
      if(sender.tag==1)
         {
           enter code here
         }
          else if (sender.tag==2)
           {
             enter code here
           }
    }
```

Comment: A `switch/case` would be even better here.